# Is there a way to filter datatable using multiple dropbox that uses sharepoint choices

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I've been trying to get this simple filter to work in my PowerApps. When adding a dropbox that uses the Choice() to call the options from my SP to the filter formula it will display "Invalid argument type".

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
ClearCollect(
    cFeedback,
    Filter(
        Feedback,
        dropCompSrch.SelectedText.Value = Company,
        Product = dropProdSrch.Selected.Value))
```

[image: PowerApps Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by just adding .Value to the column name. Below is the function.

```
ClearCollect(
cFeedback,
Filter(
    Feedback,
    dropCompSrch.SelectedText.Value = Company,
    Product.Value = dropProdSrch.Selected.Value))
```